# How to work with headers in log file? Python

Tags: python-3.x, logfile

I have log file (.txt) which I want to open and read line by line, convert the data and store with Pandas. However, it has a header with some useful information I want to grab. What is best practice when working with header sections? For example I need to grab the "CAN-bus adress" which is stored on the next row. The "CAN-bus adress" part will be the same for another file but the "460 (Machine)" will change. How do I effectively achieve that? If I run my code I get the error "TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

Any guidance would be appreciated! I could write a nasty bit of code to get this data the next time through the loop with the help of a few if statements and Booleans but there must be a better way to do this.

Also, what is a good way to detect when the header is over and the data is starting? Just compare every line with "DateTime"?

log file:

```
Developer
Raw data extractor

Date Range to extract
From    
12/18/2022
Until   
02/01/2023
CAN-bus address 
460 (Machine)



DateTime    GPStime CAN-bus data
19 December 2022 07:20:53   1671430853  0162c0c1cafe0000
19 December 2022 07:20:53   1671430853  05000000003e3c00
...
```

Code:

```
with open(filePath) as openfileobject: #Open the file
        for row, line in enumerate(openfileobject): #Read file line by line
            if line.lower() == 'CAN-bus address'.lower(): #identify the CAN message ID
                print(line)
                print(openfileobject[row+1])
```

I have tried consecutive if statments and Boolean variables to keep track on if we have found the correct row or not. It gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help.

```
skip = 0
can_addr = []
# open text file
with open("temp.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # skip space, enter lines
        line = line.strip()
        if "Developer" in line:
            # skip the line starting form Developer
            skip = 1
            continue
        if "DateTime" in line:
            # skip till the line that has "DateTime" and skip this line
            skip = 0
            continue

        if skip == 1:
            continue
        
        # At this stage, if you print(line), you will get data starting from under the line of header

        # adding address into array
        can_addr.append(line[28:38])
        
    print(can_addr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you misunderstood me. The "CAN-bus address" is in the header and on the next row the id is written "460 (Machine)". So I expext the "CAN-bus address" part to remain the same for a different file but the "460 (Machine)" part will change. 
460 (Machine)